# Create html table from two array where arrays lengths not necessary the same

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-table

I get two array as response from some server, the arrays can be with different lengths. and I want to build a table from this arrays.

For example the server response is

```
let a1=response.a1;
let a2=response.a2;
```

where

```
a1=['a','b','c'];
a2=['d','e']
```

so I want the table be like:

```
+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 |  
+------+------+
| a    | d    |
| b    | e    |
| c    |      |
+------+------+
```

and I need something like:

```
var rows=""
for(var i=0;i<a1.length;i++)
{
    for(var j=0;j<a2.length;j++)
    {
       rows+='<tr>....</tr>'
    }
}
$('#myTbody').html(rows);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tricky thing here is that 1 array can be longer than the other, so first of all:

1. find the largest array's size
2. create a loop that will add as many table rows as the longest array size
3. add the cell content to each row, handing the case that 1 array might not have any defined values at that particular array index (because different size arrays)

I've added `// 1.` `// 2.` and `// 3.` to help reference the explaination.

```js
const a1 = ['a','b','c']
const a2 = ['d','e','f','g']

const maxArrayLength = Math.max(a1.length, a2.length) // 1.

const tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');

for (let i = 0; i < maxArrayLength; i++) { // 2.
  const tr = tbody.insertRow(); // 2.
  tr.insertCell().innerHTML = a1[i] ? a1[i] : '' // 3.
  tr.insertCell().innerHTML = a2[i] ? a2[i] : '' // 3.
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col1</th>
      <th>Col2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Very nice - I was going to offer exactly the same solution. Then stopped when yours popped up -  well done :)

Comment: You can also just merge the arrays [a1,a2], and do a nested for loop to build the table. No need to compare the array length.

Comment: @Spangle in that case how would we determine which column to place the items in? And how to preserve the order? EDIT: Oh I think I know what you mean, create a 2d array?

Comment: The amount of columns will be the length of the merged array. Then loop over the length of each of the inner arrays with the nested for loop and add that as a row to that column. EDIT: yeah correct, create the 2d array :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
 const a1 = ['100','50000','60000'];
    const a2 = ['1111','22222222'];
    const greaterLength = (a1.length >= a2.length) ? a1.length : a2.length;

    let store = "";
    for(var i=0 ; i < greaterLength ; i++){
        let a1Value = (a1[i] != undefined) ? a1[i] : "";
        let a2Value = (a2[i] != undefined) ? a2[i] : "";
        store += `<tr> <td>${a1Value}</td> <td>${a2Value}</td></tr>`;
    }
    alert(store);
```

complete the table body.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML CODE :**

```
    <table id="myTbody">
    </table>
```

**Javascript code**

```
a1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
a2 = ['d', 'e'];

var maxLen = 0;
if (a1.length > a2.length) {
    maxLen = a1.length;
} else {
    maxLen = a2.length;
}

var tableHtml = '<tr><th>col1</th><th>col2</th></tr>'

for (var i = 0; i < maxLen; i++) {
    tableHtml = tableHtml + '<tr>';
    tableHtml = tableHtml + '<td>' + (i >= a1.length ? '' : a1[i]) + '</td>';
    tableHtml = tableHtml + '<td>' + (i >= a2.length ? '' : a2[i]) + '</td>';
    tableHtml = tableHtml + '</tr>';
}

$('#tabby').html(tableHtml);
```

Answer (score 0):

I mentioned this on the answer above, and just wanted to post an example of how you can get around the need to compare the length of the arrays. :)

What you can do is merge the two arrays into another array (create a 2d array), and then use the length of this merged array to get the total columns.

Then using a nested for loop, we can loop over each of the arrays in the 2d array, and add it as a row value to the column.

I have posted a simple example of this below :)

```js
let a1 = ['a','b','c'];
let a2 = ['d','e'];

// Create a 2d array
// will look like [['a','b',''c], ['d','e']];
let mergedArray = [a1 , a2];

for(let i = 0; i < mergedArray.length; i++) {
  // You would create the Column Here
  console.log(`Col${i}`);
  for(let j = 0; j < mergedArray[i].length; j++) {
    // And here is the row value.
    console.log(mergedArray[i][j]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to modify the output so that it only prints 4 rows (including header) instead of 7? Thats what the question requires